# Tem como fazer que o recálculo automático do Excel acione uma rotina em VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu tenho um esquema gráfico em **Excel** que é feito por meio de formatação condicional (ver figura abaixo), ou seja, nas células coloridas não há conteúdo, somente as cores de fundo são alteradas com base em valores de outras células.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A linha azul tracejada é feita por uma rotina em **VBA** (as conexões são complexas para se fazer também as bordas pela formatação condicional), ocorre que o usuário após lançar os valores quando precisam ser alterados, as figuras são atualizadas dinamicamente pelo próprio **Excel**, mas a linha tracejada necessita que um botão seja acionado para que o **VBA** refaça as conexões (o que é natural), ou seja, há discrepância visual entre os dados e os resultados gráficos apresentados até que a rotina seja acionada.

Isto prejudica o próprio lançamento de dados que depende do resultado desejado daquilo que se está analisando graficamente. A figura abaixo mostra esta situação, a desconexão da linha tracejada que não é alterada dinamicamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A próxima figura mostra o resultado após a rotina ser acionada por meio do botão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A rotina refaz as conexões imediatamente sem apresentar tempo de espera. O que não consegui encontrar é uma forma da rotina ser acionada dinamicamente assim que o **Excel** refaça os cálculos automaticamente para qualquer alteração que for feita na planilha.

O `Application.Calculate` aciona o cálculo no **Excel** (idem teclar `F9`) a partir do **VBA**, o que preciso é o inverso, o recálculo automático do **Excel** acionar a rotina em **VBA**.

É possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o evento `Calculate` para a worksheet em que está o botão e o gráfico, assim:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Call Sub_Usada_no_Botao

End Sub
```

Assim, toda vez que algum cálculo ocorrer na sua planilha, a `Sub` será engatilhada.

Comment: Tash_Riser, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Eu pesquisei o evento e acabei achando no SO em Inglês como fazer a mesma coisa, mas somente para determinadas células, vale a pena conferir. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388279/how-can-i-run-a-vba-code-each-time-a-cell-get-is-value-changed-by-a-formula

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente não tem uma maneira simples de fazer isso; é necessário quebrar a cabeça e bolar um sistema de *liga/desliga* do recurso `Application.Calculation`. Os modos desse recurso são:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic     'Cálculos automáticos
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual        'Cálculos automáticos desativados
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationSemiautomatic 'Cálculos automáticos, menos em tabelas
```

Uma sugestão que eu te dou é aplicar a seguinte ideia no módulo da worksheet que vc altera os dados e exibe o 'gráfico':

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub 

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate() 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 
End Sub
```

Assim, quando vc selecionar a planilha com o gráfico, o VBA vai rodar o evento `Activate`, desligando o cálculo automático, e ele se restaurará automaticamente ao acessar qualquer outra planilha. Para complementar a resposta à sua questão, basta então adicionar uma linha com `Calculate` no código que roda com seu botão para ver todas as mudanças gráficas simultaneamente ao clique do botão. Coloque no início do código para ter os resultados dos cálculos antes de manusear as bordas tracejadas.

Obviamente, vc pode pensar em outras maneiras de aplicar esse recurso, mas tenha em mente que ele SEMPRE vai se aplicar a todo o Excel (todos os arquivos abertos).

Comment: Tash_Riser, obrigado pela resposta. Para o meu caso isto não resolve, pois todo o trabalho neste gráfico é feito em uma única aba. O que é alterado são valores em células correspondentes ao desenho no esquema gráfico, portanto teria de funcionar a cada recalculo do Exzcel, quando uma célula qualquer tem seu valor alterado.

Comment: Submeti uma outra resposta. Veja se essa lhe resolve!

Answer (score 0):

O mesmo pode ser feito para **acionar uma rotina somente quando houver alteração em uma ou mais células** especificadas em uma Range.

Com base em uma das respostas para a pergunta [How can I run a VBA code each time a cell get is value changed by a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388279/how-can-i-run-a-vba-code-each-time-a-cell-get-is-value-changed-by-a-formula), encontrei uma forma mais simples para obter o mesmo resultado:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim AlterouNaFaixaDeDados As Range

 'Indique na Range a faixa que queira acionar uma rotina dinamicamente se houver alteração nas suas células
 Set AlterouNaFaixaDeDados = Application.Intersect(Range("B2:E5"), Target)

 'Se houve alteração em uma ou mais células desta Range, a rotina será acionada
 If Not AlterouNaFaixaDeDados Is Nothing Then

   'Coloque aqui a rotina a ser acionada
   Call Sub_Rotina

 End If
```

End Sub